# Connect to wireless network on different subnet

Tags: wireless, bridge

I have a lift motor that has an app that allows me to move the lift up and down.  The lift creates its on Wi-Fi network with a default gateway of 192.168.4.1
My existing network is 192.168.1.1, I have a nano station that is not being used and was hoping there was a way to bridge these two networks.
I have very limited access to change any settings in the router that is made into the lift motor.
If this is possible it would be great if the nano station could receive a wireless signal from the .1 network and wirelessly send to the .4 network.  If needed I can hardwire the nano station to the .1 network.
I would prefer not to change my network from .1 to .4, I've contacted the manufacturer of the lift about changing the subnet and they are not being very helpful.

Comment: Since they are different subnets, you will have to route between them.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer.  I have done the following.
Network Tab
...........**Network Role**

1. Network Mode = Router
2. Configuration Mode = Advanced
   ...**WAN Network Settings**
3. WAN Interface = WLAN0
4. WAN IP Address = DHCP
5. NAT = Enable
   ...**LAN Network Settings**
6. LAN Interface = LAN0
7. IP Address = 192.168.1.20
8. Netmask = 255.255.255.0
9. DHCP Server = Disabled
   **Edge Router POE Static Route**
   Destination = 192.168.4.0/24
   Next Hop = 192.168.1.20

Not sure if I've completed everything correctly, but the .4 network is secured and I dont know where i can enter the settings to connect the nano station to this network.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was originally using a NanoStation M5 and the lift motor would not show up in the 5ghz network.  I ordered a NanoStation M2 and just got it setup.  In order for you to connect it to an existing wireless network you need to put it in station mode.  Then select a SSID.  It works like a charm thank you for your help.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nanostation in Router mode. Connect it to the Lift's WLAN, set the Nanostation's WAN network to use DHCP; the address it gets here is irrelevant. Make sure you enable NAT; since you can't tell the Lift router to reach your 192.168.1.x network through the Nanostation, you need the Nanostation to NAT so the Lift just thinks it's talking to the Nanostation.

Wire your Nanostation into the .1 network, set its LAN interface to a static address in your .1.x network. On your .1 network's router, create a static route: 192.168.4.1 reachable via [nanostation LAN address]

Then your router will take you to the .4 network!